# Vector of Pointers C++ Boost Serialization Error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, vector

```
namespace featurelib
{
    typedef vector<float*> HOG_List;    
}
    void saveFeaturesFile(vector<featurelib::HOG_List> &features, string filename){
        ofstream out(filename.c_str());
        stringstream ss;
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << features;
        out << ss.str();
        out.close();
    }
```

This is my code snippet and I am trying to save `vector<featurelib::HOG_List>` into a binary file using Boost Serialization. 
But this results in an error:

> error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type

But when I remove the pointer i.e

```
typedef vector<float> HOG_List;
```

The code compiles and works fine. 
However I need to find a way to save vectors of `typedef vector<float*> HOG_List;`  to binary files using Boost

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever have a vector of `float*`?

Besides that, pointers are special to serialization because of object tracking: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking and potential polymorphism/aliasing.

Because `float` is a primitive type polymorphism is not a concern here. However, for the same reason object tracking would be unwieldy and has been disabled:

> By default, data types designated primitive by the [Implementation Level](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#level) class serialization trait are never tracked. If it is desired to track a shared primitive object through a pointer (e.g. a `long` used as a reference count), It should be wrapped in a class/struct so that it is an identifiable type. The alternative of changing the implementation level of a long would affect all longs serialized in the whole program - probably not what one would intend.

This, in turn, means that the serialization library doesn't know how to deal with `float*`

---

I'd suggest you use a ptr_vector or really think why you need the pointers.

What do the pointers mean? Replace them with an abstraction that captures the semantics. E.g. if the `float*` is /really/ the address of the first element in array like `float[32]` then redefine your `HOG_List` as being e.g.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<float> > HOG_List;
```

If you *have* to cater for "unowned" arrays, you could make do with something like GLS'd `array_view`

```
struct float_array_view {
     float* base;
     size_t n;
};

typedef std::vector<float_array_view> HOG_List;
```

**NOTE** that in such a case you *will* have to define a way to deserialize it (serialize using [boost::serialization::make_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays)). Because there's no way the library could know how to allocate the `base*`.

See also:

- [Boost serialization with template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425278/boost-serialization-with-template-classes/25484738#25484738)
- [Can't get C++ Boost Pointer Serialization to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901596/cant-get-c-boost-pointer-serialization-to-work/28907026#28907026) (this does the manual work to allocate for deserialization)
- [Boost binary serialization - double array of fixed length error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590908/boost-binary-serialization-double-array-of-fixed-length-error/28594224#28594224)

There are more potentially relevant posts here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+boost+make_array

Comment: Added links to some older answers that show how to serialize pointers in different scenarios